# Selecting row information by date

Tags: php, html, sql, database

I'm trying to display data starting at a certain time and day and ending and another time and day. here is my code:

```
<?php

include 'includes/connect3.php';

$query = "SELECT * FROM u_visits WHERE date >= '2013-08-31 22:56:20' AND date <= '2013-
08- 31 23:59:59'"; 
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

echo "<table><tr>
<th>USER ID</th>
<th>TIMES VISITED</th>
</tr>"; 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
echo "<tr><td>" . $row['id'] . "</td><td>" . $row['visits'] . "</td></tr>";  
}

echo "</table>"; 


?>
```

When I go to the page, only the table header is displayed with no data showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can also use `BETWEEN` for range comparisons.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM u_visits WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2013-08-31 22:56:20' AND '2013-08-31 23:59:59'";
```

Comment: THNAKS MAN wokred perfect i see what you did i just changed `date` to my row name and worked perfect

Answer (score 0):

The reason you didn't see any result is because your query has some errors.  The error in your query is that you have a space after `2013-08-` in your where clause (`date <= '2013-08- 31 23:59:59'";`)

Had you used proper error handling, you would have noticed this yourself.  One common way to do this is:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die ('Query execution failed: ' . mysqli_error($con));
```